# How to install Angular2 beta with Bower?

Tags: bower, angular

I'm trying to install Angular2 with Bower with command `bower install -S angular2` and have next messages in console:

```
$ bower install -S angular2
bower angular2#*                cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular2#*              validate 1.4.8 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower angular#~1.4.8           install angular#1.4.8

angular#1.4.8 bower_components/angular
```

My `bower.json` file now contains next info in `dependencies` section:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "angular2#~1.4.8"
}
```

And I have Angular 1.4.8 after that in `bower_components` path.

So, how to install Angular2 beta with Bower?

Answer (score 4):

I have installed it from github with the command `bower install git@github.com:angular/angular.git`:

```
$ bower install git@github.com:angular/angular.git
bower angular#*             not-cached git@github.com:angular/angular.git#*
bower angular#*                resolve git@github.com:angular/angular.git#*
bower angular#*               checkout 2.0.0-build.ffbcb26.js
bower angular#*           invalid-meta angular is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower angular#*           invalid-meta angular is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower angular#*               resolved git@github.com:angular/angular.git#2.0.0-build.ffbcb26.js
bower angular#~2.0.0-build.ffbcb26.js          install angular#2.0.0-build.ffbcb26.js

angular#2.0.0-build.ffbcb26.js bower_components/angular
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you not to use Bower. Bower is used to get your packages in your project folder, that's it.

Try to look up JSPM (http://jspm.io). It does a lot more than getting packages in your project. It takes care of ES6 to ES5. And loads all your packages in one time using SystemJS in your browser with just a couple lines of code.

you can install jspm using npm:

```
npm init
npm install (-g) jspm // -g only if you want jspm globally installed

jspm init
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question directly, but thanks for exposing me to jspm

Comment: This has nothing do do with what OP asked.

Comment: I know, still I think it's useful to other readers to inform them of the flaws of Bower. And because I saw OP using Angular and him wanting to install it using Bower I wanted to inform him. Might be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, for Angular 2    `bower install angular2-build`

Comment: I am -1 because this repo has not been updated in quite a while https://github.com/mgcrea/bower-angular2-build

Comment: Nice extra info.  This was helpful to me also, since it Appears Angular2 has its own extreme learning curve, just like Angular. https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Angular-2-not-available-in-Bower

Comment: Also -1 because this is the top result for "angular 2 bower" and that angular2-build is still on alpha. I'm going to guess it was never on beta and therefore this never actually answered the question.